# Error: VS800075 when downloading artifact from another project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, access-denied, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I'm doing training where I use two projects where, project A will have the artifacts that will be used and, in project B, I will build using a deployment group. During the execution of the release pipeline, the following error appears:

> Failed in getBuild with error: Error: VS800075: The project with id
> 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/0f8301ca-c8a9-4e51-bf35-73bd978f8d8d'
> does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
> at RestClient. (C:\azagent\A2_work_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.236.1\node_modules\typed-rest-client\RestClient.js:202:31)
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (C:\azagent\A2_work_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.236.1\node_modules\typed-rest-client\RestClient.js:6:58)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   statusCode: 400,
> result: [Object],   responseHeaders: [Object] } Error: VS800075: The
> project with id
> 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/0f8301ca-c8a9-4e51-bf35-73bd978f8d8d'
> does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.

Following some suggestions from Microsoft forums, I tried to add the only user I have to the Build Administrator group of project A and also to be safe I added it to project B without success.
I also tried to recreate the project, deployment group without success.

I used this reference link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-vs800075-when-downloading-artifact-from-anot/1146258